# Avoid using nested loops to find the max-sized sub-string of an array?

Tags: javascript

Added maximum number according to the input length should be returned.

For example, if the length is `2` then the max among `arr[0] + arr[1]`, `arr[1] + arr[2]`, `arr[2] + arr[3]` should be returned.

Input is array and length.

I solved this in a real job interview but I think there will be a way not to use nested loop.

```js
const add = (arr, len) => {
  let rtnVal = 0

  for (let i = len - 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let temp_idx = i;
    let temp_sum = 0;
    for (let j = 0; j < len; j++) {
      temp_sum = (temp_sum || 0) + arr[temp_idx]
      temp_idx -= 1
    }

    if (temp_sum > rtnVal) {
      rtnVal = temp_sum
    }
  }

  return rtnVal
}

console.log(add([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 4))
```

I expect the output 30

```
// enhanced nested loop

const add = (arr, len) => {
  let rtnVal = 0;
  for(let i=len-1;i<arr.length;i++){
    let sum = 0
    for(let j=i;j>=i-len+1;j--){
      sum += arr[j]
    }
    if (sum > rtnVal) rtnVal = sum
  }
  return rtnVal

}
console.log(add([9, 9, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 3))
```

Comment: Loop once, but keep head and tail “pointers”. On each move forward, add the head value and subtract the tail value from the running sum. Track max along the way.

Comment: Same base question, but some detail are different: [algorithm - How to solve "fixed size maximum subarray" using divide and conquer approach? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39966458/how-to-solve-fixed-size-maximum-subarray-using-divide-and-conquer-approach)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a moving window. Add up `len` numbers starting at the beginning. Then continue through the array adding the next number and subtracting the trailing number.

```
const add = (arr, len) => {
  return arr.reduce((a,v,i,arr) => {
    a.running += v;
    if(i >= len) {
      a.running -= arr[i-len];
    }
    if(i+1 >= len && a.largest < a.running) {
      a.largest = a.running;
    }
    return a;
  }, {
    largest: Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY,
    running: 0
  }).largest;
}

console.log(add([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],4)); // 30
console.log(add([-1,-1,-1,-1],2)); // -2
console.log(add([1],1)); // 1
```

Comment: The condition `a.largest < a.running` should only be executed when `i >= len-1`, otherwise the result would be (wrong) `-1` for `len > 1` and `arr` full of `-1`.

Comment: @user202729 I'm not sure that `i >= len-1` is correct but I do see that the constraint needs to, at least, be `i >= len` to account for negative integers near the beginning of the array. I'm going to assume that `arr.length >= len` is true.

Comment: No, this is still wrong because it doesn't take into account the leftmost array. Try `a = [1], len = 1`.

Comment: @user202729 Ah, okay, I see now.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming its sorted like your example. You can use negative slice to select from end and then reduce the array.

```js
const add = (arr, len) => arr.slice(len > arr.len ? arr.len : -len).reduce((total, num) => total + num)

console.log(add([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 4))
```

Comment: I'm sorry but your answer doesn't bring the answer I expect. I think this only works when input array values are sorted. Thanks